# In Rackspace CloudFiles should I create a container for each user uploads?

Tags: rackspace-cloud, rackspace

Just wanted to know that which one will be better: creating a different container for each user or creating only one container uploading everything related to users?

In the application part, I am going to need to list every file a user has that is why having different containers should be a good idea but on the other side, having thousands of different containers could be bad, not sure.

So, what do you think?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either way.  It would of course take a while to poll that many containers so I would reccomend having the 1 or two containers.  The query speed will be superior this way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Joe. I guess I am going to create only one container for the user uplaods as after I found out in their docs that we can create up to 500,000 containers within our accounts. Hoping that one day the app crosses the 500,000 users, not creating a seperate container for each user will better. :)

Comment: To incorporate some further segregation, you could add containers to groups perhaps. Like encyclopedia A,B,C ... P-Q ... based on some indexable property of your userinfo.  Then you would consistently know Joes are in "J" or 1251s are in "1000-2000" Some logical grouping like this might be a hybrid solution that actually increases performance at high user numbers.